# Needing direction using REGEX in Notepad++ to find length of characters in line that also contains spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a TEXT file where I have 4700 lines of a 30 character value.  The numerical characters are in position 1 through 8 and then there are only spaces supposedly after.  I am using REGEX in NOTEPAD++ to find 2 separate scenarios:

1. I would like to find if there exists on any line of my text file the length of characters in position 1-8 that are less than 6.
2. Are there any lines in my text file that have a length > 30.  I think I found the answer to this but would like some confirmation as I
   am not picking up anything in my results.  Here is my what I'm using in NOTEPAD++ find these values:  .{30, }

Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a sample of what my file looks like:

```
332268-1                      
322335                        
322375                        
322393                        
322368-1                      
322381                        
322475                        
323912-1                      
322539                        
322641                        
322641                        
322514-1                      
322638                        
322978                        
322978                        
322638-1                      
287686                        
287735                        
322579                        
322643                        
323113                        
323257                        
331875                        
331875                        
322637-1                      
322720-1                      
322745-1                      
322679                        
322702                        
322971                        
324548                        
322971                        
333146-1
```

Comment: You should be able to find newline characters with '\n'. So you could do something like \d\d\d\d\d\d\n or more cleanly \d{,6}\n
This could let you find rows that have a certain number of digits followed by a new line.
If this is a common ongoing task you could read a quick tutorial on python to run your regex on a folder of files like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 would be `^\d{0,5}\s+\n`

```
 ^ matches the beginning of the string or line
 \d digit
 {0,5} matches quantify or proceeding token
 \s whitespace
 + quantifier matches 1 or more
 \n is a new line
```

Number 2 would be `^.{31,}`

```
 ^ matches the beginning of the string or line
 . matches any character but line breaks
 {31,} matches any line that is 31 characters or greater.
```